# iterate custom dictionary object

Tags: vba, loops, object, excel, dictionary

Recently learned a bit of object oriented in Python, and I'm trying to do the same things in VBA.

I manage to construct a parent object (PC) that contains a dictionary of children objects:hooks. Hooks is also an object with a dictionary of children: rows.

All I want to do it to be able to write:

```
for each hook in PC
    for each row in hook
        sheets("X").cells(i,1) = contract.price
    next row
next hook
```

Im looking [at this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2010/07/04/custom-collection-class/) but can't make it work...

Here summary of classes:
Class PC

```
Option Explicit

Public pPC As Object
Private pName As String
Private pInclude As Boolean

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pPC = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pPC = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get hook(HookName As String) As CHook:
     Set hook = pPC(HookName)
End Property

Public Sub Add(hook As CHook):
    If Not pPC.exists(hook.Name) Then pPC.Add hook.Name, hook
End Sub

Public Property Get Include(HookName As String) As Boolean:
    pInclude = pPC.exists(HookName)
    Include = pInclude
End Property

Public Property Let Name(pcname As String):
    pName = pcname
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String:
    Name = pName
End Property
```

Class Hook

```
 Option Explicit

 Public pHook As Object
 Private pName As String
 Private pLTFlatPrice As Double
 Private pLTBasisPrice As Double
 Private pLTDate As Date

 Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pHook = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    pLTDate = Sheets("Control").Cells(2, 2)
 End Sub

 Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pHook = Nothing
 End Sub

 Public Sub AddRow(Row As CRow)
    If Not pHook.exists(Row.ContractLot) Then pHook.Add Row.ContractLot, Row
    If Row.TradeDate < pLTDate Then
        pLTDate = Row.TradeDate
        If IsNumeric(Row.FlatMV) And Row.FlatMV <> 0 Then pLTFlatPrice = Row.FlatMV
        If IsNumeric(Row.BasisMV) Then pLTBasisPrice = Row.BasisMV
    End If
 End Sub

 Public Property Get Row(ContractLot As String) As CRow:
    Set Row = pHook.Item(ContractLot)
 End Property

 Public Property Let Name(HookName As String):
    pName = HookName
 End Property

 Public Property Get Name() As String:
    Name = pName
 End Property

 Public Property Get LTFlatPrice() As Double:
    LTFlatPrice = pLTFlatPrice
 End Property

 Public Property Get LTBasisPrice() As Double:
    LTBasisPrice = pLTBasisPrice
 End Property

 Public Property Get LTDate() As Double:
    LTDate = pLTDate
 End Property
```

and here is the peace of code where the error happens (Object doesn't support this property or method):

> For i = 2 To UBound(path, 1)
>
> tName = path(i, 1)
>
> Next i
>
> Set PC = SArray.PC(tName)
>
> ```
>    For Each hook In PC
>
>        For Each row In hook
>
>             With Sheets("COB")
>
>                .Cells(ii, 2) = row.PC
>
>                .Cells(ii, 3) = row.hook
>
>                .Cells(ii, 4) = row.Period
>
>             End With
>
>        ii = ii + 1
>
>        Next row
> ```
>
> Next hook

Comment: Why do you want to do this in VBA?  Stuff like this is a lot easier to do and learn in VB.Net or C#.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: @RBarryYoung. Excellent question. Two reasons: 1) I need full integration with excel and could not find a straight forward way to do at least using Python (my code of choice). 2) True is people I work for prefer VBA because is the thing they're use to. I'm not be the one maintain the code latter. Any tips on easy interface Python X Excel are more then welcomed.

Comment: @AMariani Sorry, I cannot help you with the Python stuff.  You can use .Net stuff (and by implication Iron Python, I guess) on MS Office object models including Excel through VSTO.  As a consultant I'm stuck using VBA for all of my Excel work for site-portability reasons, however, I would encourage you to talk to your employers about the possibility of moving to VB.Net/VSTO instead.  It really is a *much* better development environment.

Comment: @TimWilliams. Added the code with the error Tim. The error is right at: for each hook in PC (Object doesn't support this property or method). I understand I need to write the method for the loop, just dont know how!

Comment: In class PC you could store your hooks in a collection and expose that via a `Hooks` property.  You can then iterate over `PC.Hooks`

Comment: @TimWilliams Not sure that's what you mean Tim but here the non-elegant solution I found:>                                                       > For i = 2 To UBound(path, 1)                   
> Set PC = SArray.PC(path(i, 1))
> For Each hkey In PC.Keys<br/>
>     Set hook = PC.hook(hkey)
> For Each rkey In hook.Keys
>     Set row = hook.row(rkey)
>     With Sheets("COB")                                              >       .Cells(ii, 2) = row.PC                                               
>       .Cells(ii, 3) = row.hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over either the keys or the items of a dictionary:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim d As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim k

    d.Add "one", 1
    d.Add "two", 2
    d.Add "three", 3

    For Each k In d.Keys
        Debug.Print k
    Next

    For Each k In d.Items
        Debug.Print k
    Next

End Sub
```

So, you can expose your dictionary as a property of an object and iterate over that.  It does mean you need to specify `.Items` though (since it will default to keys.